# Translating C++ To Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c, xml, qt

It's about some days now i'm struggling doing Archaeology work trying to translating a c++ code snippet using Qt to objective-c, it's for sending a request in order to parse xml coming from a server as a response. I really try but can't achieve it. If someone could give me some help.

```
void RestClient::_prepareRequest( QNetworkRequest& a_request, const QString& a_uri )                  {  
        QSslConfiguration config(QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration());
        config.setProtocol(QSsl::SslV3);
        config.setSslOption(QSsl::SslOptionDisableServerNameIndication, true);
        a_request.setSslConfiguration(config);
        a_request.setRawHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
        a_request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        QByteArray l_api_key; l_api_key.append( toQString( m_api_key) );
        QByteArray l_request_hash; 
    l_request_hash.append( toQString( _buildRequestHash( toStlString(a_uri) ) ) );
        a_request.setRawHeader("EMApikey", l_api_key );
        a_request.setRawHeader("EMRequestHash", l_request_hash );


        a_request.setUrl( QUrl( a_uri ) );
    }

- (NSString *)hmacsha1:(NSString *)data secret:(NSString *)key {

const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];

NSString *hash = [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:(nil)];

return hash;
```

}

and here is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

if ([stories count] == 0) {

    NSString * myServerUrl = @"**************";
    NSString * l_api_key = @"*******************************";
    NSString * l_secret_key = @"************************************";

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[myServerUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
    //do post request for parameter passing
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];


    [theRequest setValue:@"xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"xml"];

    [theRequest addValue:@"l_api_key" forHTTPHeaderField: l_api_key];

    [theRequest addValue:@"l_request_hash" forHTTPHeaderField:[self hmacsha1:l_api_key secret:l_secret_key]];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        NSLog(@"we get here !");
        NSURL *webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        [self parseXMLFileAtURL: webData];
        cellSize = CGSizeMake([newsTable bounds].size.width, 60);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }

    [theConnection release];


}

//cellSize = CGSizeMake([newsTable bounds].size.width, 60);
```

}

Comment: Why can't you continue using Qt? Your translation effort is a lot of boring work!

Comment: Because i'm not using Qt in my objective c project. can we use Qt in objective c ?

Comment: Then don't think about translating some Qt code to Objective C but about *rewriting it from scratch*. In that case, you don't really care about the old Qt code, except as a source of inspiration. Then your question might become: "how to make an HTTP request giving some XML data in Objective C" (and I have no idea about that question, not coding in Objective C!). BTW, such a question don't belong to StackOverflow, unless you show some code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Licensing most likely a good reason.

Comment: @marko: IMHO avoiding GPL is a *bad* reason, not a *good* one. But this debate is off-topic here.

Comment: I did manage to parse a Rss flux in my objective-c application i have the code and can show it, but when i try to connect to the server, it don't give me the xml response. This code snippet is the code of a friend of mine who manage to do what i'm trying to do but in Qt and c++, he kindly gave me the code and told me if i could translate it, no stollen code here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable.

Comment: Okay, thank to Basile Starynkevich anyway.

Comment: Isn't `a_request.setRawHeader("EMApikey", l_api_key );` should be equivalent `[theRequest addValue:l_api_key forHTTPHeaderField:@"EMApikey"];`?

Comment: Great :D ! Do you think i can put aside all the other methodes as setProtocol setSslOption ?

Comment: @marko Not that I'm a lawyer or anything, but I'd imagine that taking code written in one language and rewriting it in a different language still constitutes a *derived work* for the purposes of the GPL.

Comment: Cy-4AH edit an answer i will rate you as the good answer. Thanks mate.

Comment: @TristanBrindle I was referring to the license condition on QT.  can;t use the GPL license on iOS - so you're probably going to have to pay for it unless the licensing model has changed dramatically in the last couple of years.

Comment: +1 for using the words 'Archaeology' and 'C++' in the same title :)

Comment: @marko Qt has been LGPL for a few years now, which I think is acceptable in the App Store (given how many apps seem to use ffmpeg/libav). I'm not sure it actually works on iOS though! I take your point about the toolkit licence though, that didn't occur to me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a background in video games development, it is common to have to port code from one language / architecture to another. There are two ways to tackle this: -

1) Take each function / class and directly copy the code line for line.

2) Look at what a system does as a black box, with inputs and outputs and write the code yourself.

Usually number 2 is the better option as you know your own code better than someone else's and you'll do a better job that way, rather than trying to struggle to understand what another developer's intention may have been with regards to their implementation.

Therefore, I recommend that you simply try to understand what the original code is supposed to do and then write your own implementation in Objective-C. If that involves a learning curve of how to implement it, then you'll be better off for having researched and learnt what is required to do that.